# Python pyserial - windows error (2)

Tags: python, arduino, python-idle, pyserial, arduino-ide

I'm trying to use the pyserial library to connect my arduino to python, but I keep getting an error. I have my arduino connected and the serial for the arduino program is not running. I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    j = arduino()
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv and Anuj\Documents\Dhruv K. Patel\Python Files\bitSnake_source\bitSnake\glove_input.py", line 9, in __init__
    ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 38, in __init__
    SerialBase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 282, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 66, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %r: %r" % (self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM1': WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

Here's my arduino code:

```
int speed = 10;

const int thumb = 2;
const int index = 3;
const int middle = 4;
const int ring = 5;
const int pinky = 6;

String out;


void setup(){
  pinMode(thumb,INPUT);
  pinMode(index,INPUT);
  pinMode(middle,INPUT);
  pinMode(ring,INPUT);
  pinMode(pinky,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  boolean repeat = true;
  if(repeat == true){
    if(digitalRead(thumb) == HIGH){
      Serial.write(1);
      Serial.println(1);
      repeat = false;
    }
    if(digitalRead(index) == HIGH){
      Serial.write(2);
      Serial.println(2);
      repeat = false;
    }
    if(digitalRead(middle) == HIGH){
      Serial.write(3);
      Serial.println(3);
      repeat = false;
    }
    if(digitalRead(ring) == HIGH){
      Serial.write(4);
      Serial.println(4);
      repeat = false;
    }
    if(digitalRead(pinky) == HIGH){
      Serial.write(5);
      Serial.println(5);
      repeat = false;
    }
  }
  if(repeat == true){
    Serial.write(0);
    Serial.println(0);
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

And my python code:

```
import serial
from serial import *
port = 0

class arduino:

    def __init__(self):
        #serial.tools.list_ports()
        ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
        self.port = str(port)

    def read(self):

        return ser.readline()

    def close(self):

        ser.close()
```

Any help would be great, thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure COM1 (aka port 0) is the one you're actually connected to?

Answer (score 2):

Try another COM port. Your arduino obviously isn't on `COM1`.

Comment: Thank you. I was almost sure it was on COM1 - stupid mistake (*sigh*)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which COM's used in the Windows hardware device manager.

In Win7, my USB-to-serial adapter will have COM40/COM41.